# Calculating Days Between Two Dates Failing A Single Case (python, Udacity)

Tags: python, calendar

Working on a calculator that calculates the number of days between two dates specified by a user. In every case except one this calculator works, but it's unknown to me as to why this one case is failing. Here is the code I've written.

```
daysOfMonths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def month2dayz(month):
    i = 0
    month2day = 0
    while i != month - 1:
        month2day = month2day + daysOfMonths[i]
        i = i + 1
    return month2day

def leapDayz(year1, year2, month):
    leapDays = 0
    while year1 != year2 + 1:
        if year1%4 == 0:
            leapDays = leapDays + 1
        year1 = year1 + 1
    if year2%4 == 0 and month < 3:
        leapDays = leapDays - 1
    return leapDays

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    yearTday = (year2 - year1)*365

    monthTday = month2dayz(month2) - month2dayz(month1)
    leapDays = leapDayz(year1, year2, month2)

    return yearTday + monthTday + (day2 - day1) + leapDays

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"
test()
```

The case that's failing is the final one, counting the days from January 1st, 1900 to December 31st, 1999. The correct number of days is 36523, the program spits out 36524.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be treating 1900 as being a leap year.  But it's not - centuries are leap years only when they're divisible by 400 (so 1900 is not, but 2000 is, but not 2100, 2200, or 2300 either).

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, thank you, dunno how I missed that

Comment: Don't fret - everyone misses that on the their first try ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to extend the function `leapDayz`. Current implementation of this function thinks that 29-Feb leap year day is added to years that are divisible by 4. But in the Gregorian calendar, years that are divisible by 100, but not by 400, do not contain a leap day.

So, try this modification:

```
if (year1%4 == 0 and year1%100 != 0) or year1%400 == 0:
    leapDays = leapDays + 1
```

and

```
if ((year2%4 == 0 and year2%100 != 0) or year2%400 == 0) and month < 3:
    leapDays = leapDays - 1
```